# I need to eliminate punctuations from the result I am obtaining in my Text Analysis

Tags: python, nltk, word-cloud

I am trying to count the frequency of words in a dataframe column, titled df['MESSAGETEXT'] as shown below). The code (from Stackoverflow) that I am working with is below:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import string

top_N = 50

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
# RegEx for stopwords
RE_stopwords = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(stopwords))
# replace '|'-->' ' and drop all stopwords
words = (df['MESSAGETEXT']
           .str.lower()
   
           .replace([r'\|', RE_stopwords], [' ', ''], regex=True)
           .str.cat(sep=' ')
           .split()
         
)
# generate DF out of Counter
rslt = pd.DataFrame(Counter(words).most_common(top_N),
                    columns=['Word', 'Frequency']).set_index('Word')
print(rslt)

# plot
rslt.plot.bar(rot=0, figsize=(16,10), width=0.8)
```

Word Frequency count result is below and still has punctuation such as semicolon and fullstop.

```
         Frequency
Word              
'            89217
@            22231
london       20404
.            18271
-            13356
like         13153
!            10752
get          10501
&            10073
love          9720
;             9422
good          9168
one           8630
?             7943
day           7781
time          6956
know          6818
see           6811
u             6786
new           6553
think         6545
got           6330
go            6329
#london       5888
back          5801
great         5736
would         5611
x             5566
thanks        5553
people        5534
going         5464
need          5381
happy         5338
today         5040
still         4984
much          4883
thank         4766
want          4680
last          4664
well          4479
really        4444
lol           4376
please        4275
...           4210
de            4207
come          4120
even          4117
man           4094
best          4076
night         4047
```

I need to eliminate the following => ?,x,-,... etc

Comment: Do you understand what SO solution you are working does? Note: ` .replace([r'\|', RE_stopwords],...`.

Comment: Sorry, please clarify

Comment: You can add the values to be replaced in that list.

Comment: You could also use `string.punctuation` to check if its a punctuation and then build a loop which only appends to a new list when it's not a punctuation.. check this for more: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-punctuation-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

Without knowning a bit more details about the contents of the dataframe `df`, I suggest the following brute-force method:

Throw away any character that is not a letter with `.replace([r'[^a-zA-Z]'], [' '], regex=True)` and in `is_valid` check that words are not in `stopwords` and have at least length 3.

```py
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import nltk

top_N = 50

stopwords = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))


def is_valid(w):
    return len(w) > 2 and w not in stopwords


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {'MESSAGETEXT': [open("sampletext.txt").read()]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['MESSAGETEXT'])

    words = (df['MESSAGETEXT']
             .str.lower()
             .replace([r'[^a-zA-Z]'], [' '], regex=True)
             .str.cat(sep=' ')
             .split()
             )

    filtered_words = [w for w in words if is_valid(w)]
    most_common = Counter(filtered_words).most_common(top_N)
    rslt = pd.DataFrame(most_common, columns=['Word', 'Frequency']).set_index('Word')
    print(rslt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the need to modify your code, it could be simply adding two lines at the end of the code to remove the unwanted rows from the resulted DataFram (assume to be `rslt`) as in the next lines, either:

```
remov_list='=>?x-'  # unwanted symbols
rslt=rslt[rslt['Word'].apply(lambda x: x not in remove_list)]
```

or

```
remov_list='=>?x-'  # unwanted symbols
rslt=rslt.drop(rslt[rslt['Word'].apply(lambda x: x in remove_list)].index,axis=0)
```